# Scrolltop not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Does anyone have any idea why the following script does not reset the place of the page to the top? (The autoscrolling works fine) I am look for the fix to be compatable in IE...

```
 function getheight() {

                var myWidth = 0,
            myHeight = 0;
             if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
                    //Non-IE
                    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
                    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
                } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
                    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
                    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
                    //IE 4 compatible
                    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
                }
                var scrolledtonum = window.pageYOffset + myHeight + 2;
                var heightofbody = document.body.offsetHeight;
                if (scrolledtonum >= heightofbody) {
                    document.body.scrollTop(0, 0);
                }
            }

            window.onscroll = getheight; 

            function func() {
                window.document.body.scrollTop++;
            }

            window.document.onmouseover = function () {
                clearInterval(interval);
            };

            window.document.onmouseout = function () {
                interval = setInterval(func, 20);
            };

            var interval = setInterval(func, 20);
```

Comment: Check your css - by me the problem was that I had 'overflow: scroll' set to a child in the body, and not to the body/html itself, so I had to animate the child div and not the body/html (so instead of $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow"); I had to do $('.child-element').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow"); )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
document.body.scrollTop(0, 0);
```

[scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) is not a method call.

Did you mean [`window.scrollTo(0,0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scrollTo) or `document.body.scrollTop = 0;`?

Comment: I used window.scrollTo(0,0) and it works in Chrome. However, it still does not work in IE (Well, at least IE7) Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `scrolledtonum >= heightofbody` is true in IE?

Comment: No, that statement is not compatible with IE. How could I replicate it with the same result in a method that is compatible with IE?